# Google music player queue

Tags: music-player

I have read numerous posts about adding songs to the queue. My issue is I select a song and start it playing, I then select the next song and click the 3 dots next to the title and select "add to queue". I do this for several songs. I then click on the title bar and select the icon to view the queue and instead of showing the songs I added to the queue the queue now lists every song in my library not just the songs I added. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to play selectef songs back to back it is recommended to create a playlist of the songs you tend to listen more often. It is quite easy way and reliable as well.

Add to queue is nothing but to add the songs it is showing right in the list.

If you want to play few songs at once back to back please choose 'play next' option, as your concern is by choosing 'play next' option let's say for 5 songs, your 5 songs will listed just below your currently played songs and after 5 songs you will see list of all the songs from library.